# Give a list of all the numbers $n$ such that $n$ has a primitive root

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Is there a way of generalizing all the numbers that have primitive roots?

Answer (score 1):

You say "generalizing", but I think you mean "generating." I answer as though the question said the latter.

Yes, it's very easy to know which integers have primitive roots. $n$ has a primitive root if and only if $n$ is $2, 4, p^k,$ or $2p^k$, where $p$ is any odd prime and $k$ is any positive integer.

Comment: Is there something you can point me to for that? Thanks.

Comment: @jchen114 Wikipedia has it under primitive roots, or any basic number theory text. A good thing to look for is 'generators of the unit group.'